# Multi continents shown when at max zoom in leaflet - data only shown on center continent

Tags: leaflet

New user to Leaflet here and I've developed a mapping application that pulls geoJSON from an Oracle db.  This all works but if I zoom Leaflet all the way out where it shows multiple copies of the continent my data only shows if I zoom into the center continent.  My questions are is this normal?  How to you prevent the user from panning to another continent while continuing to move in an east or west direction?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can set a `minZoom` property to avoid this.

Something like:

```
var map = L.map('map', {
    center: [51.505, -0.09],
    minZoom: 4,
    zoom: 13
});
```

[Docs Reference](http://leafletjs.com/reference.html#map-minzoom)

**EDIT:** Maybe I misunderstand your question.

To restrict the map view to the given bounds you use:

```
map.setMaxBounds(LatLngBounds);
```

[setMaxBounds Reference](http://leafletjs.com/reference.html#map-setmaxbounds)

***More specifically:***

```
map.setMaxBounds(L.latLngBounds(
    L.latLng(85, -180),    
    L.latLng(-85, 180)    
));
```

Answer (score 0):

I suspect that's normal, I don't believe Leaflet tries to duplicate markers in high-zoom states.

You might try enabling [`map.worldCopyJump`](http://leafletjs.com/reference.html#map-worldcopyjump), which sounds like it might work for your purpose:

> With this option enabled, the map tracks when you pan to another
>   "copy" of the world and seamlessly jumps to the original one so that
>   all overlays like markers and vector layers are still visible.

If that fails, try limiting the `minZoom` and/or setting `maxBounds`, [like in this example](https://www.mapbox.com/mapbox.js/example/v1.0.0/maxbounds/):

```js
var southWest = L.latLng(40.712, -74.227),
    northEast = L.latLng(40.774, -74.125),
    bounds = L.latLngBounds(southWest, northEast);

var map = L.map('map', {
    // set that bounding box as maxBounds to restrict moving the map
    // see full maxBounds documentation:
    // http://leafletjs.com/reference.html#map-maxbounds
    maxBounds: bounds,
    maxZoom: 19,
    minZoom: 10
});

// zoom the map to that bounding box
map.fitBounds(bounds);
```